# after enabling Xinerama (in AMD condor Dual-Head Graphics Card) the system graphics hangs

Tags: rhel, xorg, kernel-modules, multi-monitor, xinerama

I have a problem in my AMD Condor Dual-Head Graphics Card

When I enable Xinerama from "System → Preferences → AMD Catalyst Control center (Administrative)"  my RHEL Server 6.3 (x64) Graphics hangs.

I need to choose disable it from console <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, login as root, off Xinerama from `xorg.conf`.

While switching from initlevel 3 to initlevel 5 I got following error.

```
Loading TSI condorvc device driver moduleinsmod: error inserting '/lib/modules/video/condorvc-mod.ko'': -1 File exists
```